# How to prevent Nashorn's implicit type conversion

Tags: javascript, java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, nashorn

I am trying to call a Java method with one integer parameter from JavaScript which is interpreted by Nashorn JavaScript engine.

Everything works fine until String value is passed as method argument. This String is implicitly converted by Nashorn to integer with value 0 without any error or warning. My desired behavior is to fail in Nashorn when trying to find proper method.

Is there any option how to turn off this implicit type conversion or any other workaround how to prevent Nashorn to do this conversion?

Thanks for you answers :-)